# React typescript .tsx files extensions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm changing my react project to react-typescript. I already created tsconfig and eslintrc and everything is ready and working. I also changed all my js files to tsx files. But now I'm getting an Error that it does not recognize `import App from "./App"` and I need to add the .tsx `"./App.tsx"`. I know I can change the webpack config file and I added this:

```
module.exports = {
resolve: {
    enforceExtension: false,
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
},
};
```

But it didn't help, still getting the same error.
How can I change the configuration file so it will know to read the .tsx files?
Should I change the eslintrc? tsconfig? or webpack?
Thanks

P.s I used Create React App so I already have the default webpack configuration

Comment: Can you try adding this field to ts.config.lib.json: "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the full wepback config?

Comment: I'm using the default Create React App Webpack config so didn't add extra configuration. Here are my eslint and ts config: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-fermi-pp5fi?file=/eslintrc.js

Comment: Can you kindly share how the root `index` file is named as well the `app` file? I'm especially interested in the extensions used for both files. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So eventually it was my mistake. If you create a react App with CRA, webpack already knows how to handle the tsx extensions no need to add ANYTHING! Just re-complie it. it was a stupid mistake by defiantly learn from it